# Generate css for different themes in less at one go?

Tags: css, less

I use less for theming. I have a couple of themes of different colors.What i do now is comment other variables definitions , leaving out variables for one theme and compile less to css. I generate the css for all others themes repeating this for other themes. Is there any other way where I could generate all theme css at once ?

I am even ready to change the structure of my less files.

Answer (score 0):

You can always divide your stylesheets into two -- variables and then the theme. Say variables.less and theme.less

If you make the general theming variables abstract enough (say @primary and @secondary for colors), you can write as many variable.less sheets you would like, and decide which to show dynamically through jquery. Then the theme.less will stay constant, and the variables which populate it will be placed dynamically in there by how you decide to do so using jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,

Based on that theme name you have to create the css file like theme1.css,theme2.css .

So based on that you check with which theme you currently running and based on that theme.css you can load.

Comment: My problem is not on loading the theme at client , but to compile the different css files at once for all the themes .